# Determining cache sector size for a processor

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, micro-optimization, microprocessors

I'm trying to build tests around processor cache-line optimizations relative to parallel processing. Specifically, I'm testing how segments of my products are being impacted by **False Sharing** inefficiencies. To do this, I need to be able to determine my processors *cache sector size* (*Ex. 64 bytes*) so I can contrive tests with the appropriate object size ranges. So... how or where can I get this information (e.g. processor spec page, C# API call, etc...)? Cache sector size is also known as Cache Line size.

*Note: I looked on the Intel site for my i7 processor spec and can't find these details, or maybe I just can't recognize it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a similar experiment. I use [CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and find it extremely helpful with detailed information about CPU cores, caches (L1, L2, etc)...

My suggestion: don't be distracted too much by hardware specs, focus on benchmarking because your experiment is going to take a lot of time.

Comment: This did the trick although it only shows the cache line size if its available in the description. In my case, that worked. Thanks.